# How can I setup dependencies for Axis2 / Axiom on Maven2

Tags: maven-2, apache-axis, axiom

I've tried the following settings on `pom.xml` to use Axis2 `wsdl2code`:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
   <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
...

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
      <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.1</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <packageName>com.example.package</packageName> 
            <wsdlFile>http://example.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1</wsdlFile>
            <databindingName>xmlbeans</databindingName> 
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
  ...
</build>
```

Whenever I run `mvn clean`, I get the following warnings with a `ClassNotFoundException` showing no signs of `org.apache.axiom`.

```
[WARNING] POM for 'commons-io:commons-io:pom:1.4:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project commons-io:commons-io at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\1.4\commons-io-1.4.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-api\1.2.8\axiom-api-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-impl\1.2.8\axiom-impl-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-dom\1.2.8\axiom-dom-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'javax.mail:mail:pom:1.4:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project javax.mail:mail at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\javax\mail\mail\1.4\mail-1.4.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'xalan:xalan:pom:2.7.0:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project xalan:xalan at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.0\xalan-2.7.0.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:pom:1.0.1:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec\1.0.1\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'commons-io:commons-io:pom:1.4:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project commons-io:commons-io at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\1.4\commons-io-1.4.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'xalan:xalan:pom:2.7.0:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project xalan:xalan at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.0\xalan-2.7.0.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-api\1.2.8\axiom-api-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-impl\1.2.8\axiom-impl-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-dom\1.2.8\axiom-dom-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'javax.mail:mail:pom:1.4:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project javax.mail:mail at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\javax\mail\mail\1.4\mail-1.4.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'xalan:xalan:pom:2.7.0:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project xalan:xalan at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.0\xalan-2.7.0.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:pom:1.0.1:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec\1.0.1\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'commons-io:commons-io:pom:1.4:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project commons-io:commons-io at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\1.4\commons-io-1.4.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:pom:1.4.9:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-utils\1.4.9\plexus-utils-1.4.9.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-api\1.2.8\axiom-api-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-impl\1.2.8\axiom-impl-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-dom\1.2.8\axiom-dom-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'javax.mail:mail:pom:1.4:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project javax.mail:mail at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\javax\mail\mail\1.4\mail-1.4.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'xalan:xalan:pom:2.7.0:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project xalan:xalan at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.0\xalan-2.7.0.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:pom:1.0.1:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec\1.0.1\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'commons-io:commons-io:pom:1.4:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project commons-io:commons-io at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\1.4\commons-io-1.4.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:pom:2.0.7:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-plugin-api\2.0.7\maven-plugin-api-2.0.7.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:pom:2.0.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.maven:maven-artifact at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-artifact\2.0.8\maven-artifact-2.0.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.maven:maven-project:pom:2.0.7:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.maven:maven-project at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-project\2.0.7\maven-project-2.0.7.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-api\1.2.8\axiom-api-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-impl\1.2.8\axiom-impl-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-dom\1.2.8\axiom-dom-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'javax.mail:mail:pom:1.4:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project javax.mail:mail at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\javax\mail\mail\1.4\mail-1.4.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'xalan:xalan:pom:2.7.0:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project xalan:xalan at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.0\xalan-2.7.0.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:pom:1.0.1:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec\1.0.1\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'commons-io:commons-io:pom:1.4:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project commons-io:commons-io at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\1.4\commons-io-1.4.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-api\1.2.8\axiom-api-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-impl\1.2.8\axiom-impl-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-dom\1.2.8\axiom-dom-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'javax.mail:mail:pom:1.4:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project javax.mail:mail at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\javax\mail\mail\1.4\mail-1.4.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'xalan:xalan:pom:2.7.0:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project xalan:xalan at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.0\xalan-2.7.0.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:pom:1.0.1:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec\1.0.1\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'commons-io:commons-io:pom:1.4:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project commons-io:commons-io at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\1.4\commons-io-1.4.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-api\1.2.8\axiom-api-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-impl\1.2.8\axiom-impl-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-api\1.2.8\axiom-api-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-impl\1.2.8\axiom-impl-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-api\1.2.8\axiom-api-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-impl\1.2.8\axiom-impl-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-api\1.2.8\axiom-api-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-impl\1.2.8\axiom-impl-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-dom\1.2.8\axiom-dom-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'javax.mail:mail:pom:1.4:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project javax.mail:mail at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\javax\mail\mail\1.4\mail-1.4.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'xalan:xalan:pom:2.7.0:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project xalan:xalan at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.0\xalan-2.7.0.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:pom:1.0.1:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec\1.0.1\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'commons-io:commons-io:pom:1.4:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project commons-io:commons-io at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\1.4\commons-io-1.4.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-api\1.2.8\axiom-api-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-impl\1.2.8\axiom-impl-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-dom\1.2.8\axiom-dom-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'javax.mail:mail:pom:1.4:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project javax.mail:mail at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\javax\mail\mail\1.4\mail-1.4.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'xalan:xalan:pom:2.7.0:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project xalan:xalan at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.0\xalan-2.7.0.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:pom:1.0.1:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec\1.0.1\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'commons-io:commons-io:pom:1.4:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project commons-io:commons-io at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\1.4\commons-io-1.4.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-api\1.2.8\axiom-api-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-impl\1.2.8\axiom-impl-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-api\1.2.8\axiom-api-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-impl\1.2.8\axiom-impl-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-api\1.2.8\axiom-api-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-impl\1.2.8\axiom-impl-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-api\1.2.8\axiom-api-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-impl\1.2.8\axiom-impl-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-dom\1.2.8\axiom-dom-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'javax.mail:mail:pom:1.4:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project javax.mail:mail at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\javax\mail\mail\1.4\mail-1.4.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'xalan:xalan:pom:2.7.0:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project xalan:xalan at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.0\xalan-2.7.0.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:pom:1.0.1:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec\1.0.1\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'commons-io:commons-io:pom:1.4:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project commons-io:commons-io at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\1.4\commons-io-1.4.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-api\1.2.8\axiom-api-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-impl\1.2.8\axiom-impl-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-dom\1.2.8\axiom-dom-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'javax.mail:mail:pom:1.4:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project javax.mail:mail at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\javax\mail\mail\1.4\mail-1.4.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'xalan:xalan:pom:2.7.0:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project xalan:xalan at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.0\xalan-2.7.0.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:pom:1.0.1:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec\1.0.1\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'commons-io:commons-io:pom:1.4:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project commons-io:commons-io at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\1.4\commons-io-1.4.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-api\1.2.8\axiom-api-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-impl\1.2.8\axiom-impl-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-dom\1.2.8\axiom-dom-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'javax.mail:mail:pom:1.4:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project javax.mail:mail at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\javax\mail\mail\1.4\mail-1.4.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:pom:1.0.1:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec\1.0.1\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'commons-io:commons-io:pom:1.4:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project commons-io:commons-io at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\1.4\commons-io-1.4.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-api\1.2.8\axiom-api-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-impl\1.2.8\axiom-impl-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-dom\1.2.8\axiom-dom-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'javax.mail:mail:pom:1.4:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project javax.mail:mail at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\javax\mail\mail\1.4\mail-1.4.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'xalan:xalan:pom:2.7.0:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project xalan:xalan at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.0\xalan-2.7.0.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:pom:1.0.1:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec\1.0.1\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'commons-io:commons-io:pom:1.4:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project commons-io:commons-io at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\1.4\commons-io-1.4.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-api\1.2.8\axiom-api-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-impl\1.2.8\axiom-impl-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom:pom:1.2.8:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-dom\1.2.8\axiom-dom-1.2.8.pom
[WARNING] POM for 'javax.mail:mail:pom:1.4:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project javax.mail:mail at C:\Users\Ronaldo\.m2\repository\javax\mail\mail\1.4\mail-1.4.pom
...
```

Answer (score 4):

I had lots of trouble to get the whole thing working with the version 1.5.1 of the plugin.

First, I faced the corrupted artifacts problem mentioned in [this thread](http://old.nabble.com/Problem-running-axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin-td26353997.html) that can be solved by applying the workaround of [AXIS2-4549](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-4549): add a mirror to your `~/.m2/settings.xml`:

```
  <mirrors>
    <!-- Workaround for https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-4549 -->
    <mirror>
      <id>java.net.2</id>
      <name>java.net Mirror of http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
      <mirrorOf>java.net</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors
```

Be sure to clean `~/.m2/repository/org/apache/axis2` after this.

Then, it appears that [wsdl2java needs axiom jars when using xmlbeans bindings](http://markmail.org/message/g7ohwwxngojcxf75). So add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
  <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Strangely, Maven reported problems about corrupted artifacts several times and I add to delete both `~/.m2/repository/org/apache/ws/commons/axiom/` and `~/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/` in the process to retrieve working artifacts.

After this, the build was working (not passing because of compilation problems but working).

P.S.: To be honest, this was really an awful experience and the situation seems very unstable. One more reason to stay away from Axis2 IMHO and to prefer JAX-WS RI or CXF.

Comment: I am collecting disadvantages of Axis2... maybe because I don't want to learn yet another technology when there is JAX-WS :) AFAIK, CXF is build on the top of JAX-WS, but has so many nice features integrated. So, what would you suggest to migrate from Axis to: pure JAX-WS or CXF?

Comment: @dma_k I had good experience with both JAX-WS RI and CXF. But I'd say that CXF offers more flexibility, easier Spring integration, better documentation, more tutorials, and some nice extra features. So I'd probably pick CXF (but stick to the JAX-WS standard as much as possible). Oh, and just in case, have a look at this [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588616/java-webservice-client-best-way/3590252#3590252). Axis2 and me = never again :)